# My Pine script V5 strategy opens many trades on the same bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

How can I force my pine script code to enter only one trade per bar even if this trade has been closed due to SL/TP, I want to force it to wait until new candle is formed to check the entry criteria.

How can I force my pine script code to enter only one trade per bar even if this trade has been closed due to SL/TP, I want to force it to wait until new candle is formed to check the entry criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I just changed the na with 1 and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index()` to get the bar index of the last closed position. Then compare this with the current bar index to get the bars since the exit.

```
// Calculate the amount of bars since the last closed trade.
barsSinceClosed = strategy.closedtrades > 0 ? bar_index - strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades - 1) : na

plot(barsSinceClosed, "Bars since last closed trade")
```

Use `barsSinceClosed` as a condition to enter a trade. Something like `(barsSinceClosed > 0) and (your_entry_condition)`

Comment: Hard to help without seeing your code..